# robot framework python module import issues

Tags: python, import, robotframework

I have custom packages and there is issue while importing while running robot tests
my project has two modules:

```
main :
  commans :
     libraries :
          read_data.py
  project :
     generate_data.py
     tests :
         test_online.robot
```

here test_online.robot calling keyword from generate_data.py

and generate_data.py importing method from commons/libraries/read.py

but i am getting no module found commons error.

running command from **main**:
robot project/tests/test_onlne.robot

Comment: Ensure that you have a \_\_init\_\_.py file for each folder expected to be used as a package

Comment: yes all module has init.py file